# mySql: `SELECT`` statement with `OR` and `AND`

Tags: mysql, sql

I am confused about why I am getting rows returned from a query...

Here is the query, it searches for the existence of a string in a single table.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `donor` 
 WHERE `col1` LIKE '%test%' 
    OR `col2` LIKE '%test%' 
    OR `col3` LIKE '%test%' 
    OR `col4` LIKE '%test%' 
   AND `delete` = 0
```

The last line `AND delete = 0` is returning rows whose 'delete' column is '1'? Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the WHERE clause as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `donor` WHERE 
(`col1` LIKE '%test%' OR 
`col2` LIKE '%test%' OR 
`col3` LIKE '%test%' OR 
`col4` LIKE '%test%')
AND `delete` =0
```

You want to or the first set of criteria together and then perform the AND operation.

Comment: +1: Needs brackets for the criteria to be applied properly.  But could really benefit by switching to Full Text Search (FTS) functionality

Comment: Always put your parenthesis in for logic tests with both `OR`s and `AND`s, specifically to avoid this sort of issue.  Future maintainers will thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to group the conditions together by enclosing them in brackets `()`. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `donor` WHERE 
(`col1` LIKE '%test%' OR 
`col2` LIKE '%test%' OR 
`col3` LIKE '%test%' OR 
`col4` LIKE '%test%') AND
`delete` =0
```